# String combination function doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, string

> Given two strings s1 and s2 as input, create a string made of the first char of s1, the first char of s2, the second char of s1, the second char of s2, and so on. Any leftover chars go at the end of the result string.

**My approach**

To combine first String of str1 and another String of str2,I took each character from str1 and str2 and tried to append it.I got correct output when the string length is equal.But String 1 length is less than String 2 length I am getting incorrect output.

```
public String combine(String str1,String str2)
 {

  int l1=str1.length();
 int l2=str2.length();
 String strnew="";
 if(l1>=l2)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<l1;j++)
     {
         char c1=str1.charAt(j);
         strnew=strnew+c1;
         for(int p=j;p<=j && p<l2 ;p++) @Edit
         {
             char c2=str2.charAt(p);
             strnew=strnew+c2;
         }
     }
 }
 else
 {
     for(int j=0;j<l2;j++)
     {
         char c1=str1.charAt(j);
         strnew=strnew+c1;
         for(int p=j;p<=j && p<l1;p++)   @Edit
         {
             char c2=str2.charAt(p);
             strnew=strnew+c2;
         }
     }
 }
 return strnew;

}
```

Output:

```
       Parameters        Actual Output  Expected Output

 Pass   'abc' '123'       a1b2c3         a1b2c3

 Fail   'Hi' 'Hello'    null             HHiellot
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to build up the resulting string.

Comment: `for(int p=j;p<=j;p++)` you may want to have a closer look at this loop. How many iterations do you expect ?

Comment: this code actually throws an exception for the Fail output not null!

Comment: What does it mean the title? Fix it, please. It will help future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is when one string is long than the other, you don't bound the inner loop to that length.
You can correct it by adding `p < l2` and `p < l1` in the nested loops as stop condition in addition to what you've already set.

```
    public static String combine(String str1,String str2)
    {

        int l1=str1.length();
        int l2=str2.length();
        String strnew="";
        if(l1>=l2)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<l1;j++)
            {
                char c1=str1.charAt(j);
                strnew=strnew+c1;
                for(int p=j;p<=j && p<l2;p++)
                {
                    char c2=str2.charAt(p);
                    strnew=strnew+c2;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=0;j<l2;j++)
            {
                char c1=str1.charAt(j);
                strnew=strnew+c1;
                for(int p=j;p<=j && p < l1;p++)
                {
                    char c2=str2.charAt(p);
                    strnew=strnew+c2;
                }
            }
        }
        return strnew;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code: explain what you have changed.

Comment: My bad, I was just editing when I recieved your comment. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: @PaulK. Please correct the code.I got last test case wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to to use a nested loop. You could use a single loop like this.

```
public static String combine(String str1,String str2) {
    String output = "";
    // Loop as long as i < as str1.length or str2.length
    for(int i = 0; i<str1.length() || i < str2.length(); ++i) {
        if(i<str1.length()) { // add the char at i to the ouput if there is a char left to take
            output += str1.charAt(i);
        }
        if(i<str2.length()) { // add the char at i to the ouput if there is a char left to take
            output += str2.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Output:

```
a1b2c3 
Trisect
```

As Bathsheba said it´s better to not use a `String` here, instead you could use a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String combine(String str1,String str2) {
    //Use the complete length as initial capizity
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(str1.length()+str2.length()); 
    for(int i = 0; i<str1.length() || i < str2.length(); ++i) {
        if(i<str1.length()) {
            output.append(str1.charAt(i));
        }
        if(i<str2.length()) {
            output.append(str2.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Don't use a string for all these concatenations. Pretty please.

Answer (score 3):

This is the clearest way I can think of. I like the fact that the "tail string" will be added as part of the regular algorithm. Note the null checks and the use of `StringBuilder`:

```
String combine(String s1, String s2)
    {
        if (s1 == null && s2 == null){
            return null;
        } else if (s1 == null){
            return s2;
        } else if (s2 == null){
            return s1;
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int pos = 0; pos < Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length()); ++pos){
                if (pos < s1.length()){
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(pos));
                }
                if (pos < s2.length()){
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(pos));
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();            
        }        
    }
```

I imagine that the repeated calls to `max` will be optimised out due to string immutability. However, it will still make some unnecessary length checks.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach with nicely wierd for loops :

```
public static String combine(String str1,String str2) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int str1size = str1 == null ? 0 : str1.length();
    int str2size = str2 == null ? 0 : str2.length();
    int lowerSize = Math.min(str1size, str2size);
    int greaterSize = Math.max(str1size, str2size);
    int i;  // define the counter variable outside of a for, because we will reuse it in the following for loops
    for (i=0; i < lowerSize; i++) {                              // browse the common part of the strings
        result.append(str1.charAt(i)).append(str2.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int upTo = Math.min(greaterSize, str1size); i < upTo ; i++) {     // browse the remaining part of str1, if applicable
        result.append(str1.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int upTo = Math.min(greaterSize, str2size); i < upTo; i++) {     // browse the remaining part of str2, if applicable
        result.append(str2.charAt(i));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/tc5NbQ).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach; convert the strings into char [], like this

```
char [] arrstr1 = str1.toCharArray();
```

then choose the smaller array, and iterate on it selecting each time the i-th charachter of each array.
Then, add the remaning chars of the bigger string.

edit: added some more code for better explaination

```
char [] arrstr1 = str1.toCharArray();
char [] arrstr2 = str2.toCharArray();
String res="";
int i=0;
for(; i<arrstr1.length || i<arrstr2.length ; i++){
   res+=arrstr1[i]+arrstr2[i];
}
if(arrstr1.length >i) res+= str1.substring(i);
if(arrstr2.length >i) res+= str2.substring(i);
```

Not great perfomances, but it should work

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to give this a shot

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCombiner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstWord="", secondWord="", remainingLetters="", newWord = "";

        System.out.print("enter first word: ");
        firstWord = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("enter second word: ");
        secondWord = scan.nextLine();

        int firstWordLength = firstWord.length();
        int secondWordLength = secondWord.length();

        if(firstWordLength==secondWordLength){

            newWord = combine(firstWord,secondWord);

        }else if(firstWordLength>secondWordLength){

            remainingLetters= firstWord.substring(secondWordLength, firstWordLength);

            firstWord = firstWord.substring(0,firstWordLength-remainingLetters.length());

            newWord = combine(firstWord, secondWord,remainingLetters);

        }else{

            remainingLetters = secondWord.substring(firstWordLength,secondWordLength);

            secondWord = secondWord.substring(0,secondWordLength-remainingLetters.length());

            newWord = combine(firstWord, secondWord,remainingLetters);

        }

        System.out.print("combined word: "+ newWord);
    }

    private static String combine(String firstWord, String secondWord,
            String remainingLetters) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return combine(firstWord, secondWord)+remainingLetters;
    }

    private static String combine(String firstWord, String secondWord) {

        String word = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<firstWord.length();i++){
            word+=firstWord.charAt(i);
            word+=secondWord.charAt(i);
        }
        return word;

    }
}
```

Basically, I have two methods with same name, but different number of arguments (method overloading)

First, We'll determine which has the longest word:

if it's equal (example, abc and 123), just call combine with two strings as parameter .

combine(abc,123);

Otherwise, we'll get the excess of the longest word, then cut it to match the smaller word.

e.g.

tiet
rsc

we'll store the excess letters in a variable named remainingLetters, then cut the longest word (tiet) to match the length of the second word. so the result will look like this:

```
firstWord = tie
secondWord = rsc
remainingLetters = t
```

then call combine with three parameters (firstWord, secondWord, remainingLetters)

the combine method with three parameters works almost the same as combine with two parameters, it's just that we add the remaining letters at the end.

Comment: I can't use any inbuilt function except what I have used.